# shopping cart observer

Tags: magento

I am trying to work something out in Magento, but I'm not sure what the best way of doing things are.

I am selling fabric/material, which is expensive. I am therefore allowing customers to purchase 'samples' of these fabrics.

What I need to do is:
* Each of these samples are free ($00.00), but..
* If the customer has 5 or more items (no more than 15 items) then I need to add a surcharge of $20 (to cover P&P etc)

So if a customer has added 8 samples to their cart, they need to be charged whatever they have in their cart currently, plus $20 for the samples.

Could I do this in an observer method?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with an observer, yes. To find relevant events for you to use, use this in the command line:

```
grep -rin -B2 -A2 "Mage::dispatchEvent" app/* > events.txt
```

Now you can easily search the `events.txt` file for *cart*. Personally I would make an effort to update the cart, and not just update the total during checkout. Don't want to surprise visitors with any extra charges. So here are a few that might help:

```
checkout_cart_update_items_after
checkout_cart_product_add_after
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
checkout_cart_update_item_complete
checkout_cart_save_before
checkout_cart_save_after
```